# NumberFormat doesn't like more than 340 decimal places

Tags: java

I want to format a double with a certain number of decimal places in Java. My code currently looks like this:

```
    final NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    format.setMinimumFractionDigits(decimalPlaces);
    format.setMaximumFractionDigits(decimalPlaces);
    format.setGroupingUsed(false);
    String s = format.format(value);
```

but when `decimalPlaces` is more than 340, this method just prints 340 digits and  ignores the rest. Is there a way to work around this limitation?

Specifically in my case they're all 0s (and probably would be with any number after a certain point since the precision is not that high) but it seems wrong to me that the function just silently ignores what I want instead of throwing an exception or something.

Yes, I'm aware that a double can't actually hold that many decimal places, but it's also true that an int can't hold any decimal places at all yet I'm able to print it with some.

Comment: Can you include what is the value you have for "decimalPlaces"

Comment: This is for an assignment. We have to make a simple command-line calculator and in one of the tests there is a 0 result that has to be printed with 500 decimal places (all zero's). This method cuts them off at 340 and doesn't even show any error.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that we're not supposed to make our own printing function.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of [setMinimumFractionDigits](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMinimumFractionDigits-int-) contains this statement:

> The concrete subclass may enforce an upper limit to this value appropriate to the numeric type being formatted.

Most likely the subclass returned by `NumberFormat.getInstance` is `DecimalFormat`, which tells us in the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setMinimumFractionDigits-int-)

> For formatting numbers other than BigInteger and BigDecimal objects, the lower of newValue and 340 is used. Negative input values are replaced with 0.

So to solve your problem, convert your number to a `BigDecimal` before formatting it.

Comment: I found that now in the documentation, but is there a not a simpler way to do this?

Comment: I think it is pretty simple - and it is a relatively reasonable limitation. You rarely need to print that many decimal places if you don't use a data type that can represent a number with such precision...

Comment: Ok I guess it's simple, but pretty wasteful of resources. This is a homework from a time where we didn't even learn about classes yet. I think we're supposed to do it with printf or something but that seems even worse to me to format the number into a string for printf to parse it again.

Comment: Don't worry about being "pretty wasteful of resources". Those bits get reused.

Answer (score 0):

In case of double the value is getting truncating. Use/declare value as `BigDecimal`

Try this sample code:

```
    final NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    format.setMinimumFractionDigits(355);
    format.setMaximumFractionDigits(400);
    format.setGroupingUsed(false);
    System.out.println(format.getMinimumFractionDigits());
    BigDecimal bd=new BigDecimal(10L);
    String s = format.format(bd);
    System.out.println(s.length());
    System.out.println(s);
```